# problems with exercise, when checking, an inscription appears that there are wrong answers, but I can not understand what the error is

Tags: python

```
n, m = map(int, input().split())
matrix = [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(n)]
k = int(input())
sum = 0
rad = 0
naydeno = False
for i in range(n):
    for l in range(m):
        if l != (m - 1) and (matrix[i][l] + matrix[i][l + 1] == 0):
            sum += 1
    if sum >= k - 1 and sum != 0:
        rad = i
        naydeno = True
        break
    sum = 0
# for index, row in enumerate(matrix):
#     count = 0
#     for i in range(len(row) - 1):
#         if row[i] == 0 and row[i + 1] == 0:
#             count += 1
#         if count == 0 and 0 in row:
#             count = 1
#     if count >= k:
#         print(index + 1)
#         break
    # print(index, count)
if naydeno:
    print(rad + 1)
if naydeno == False:
    print(rad)
```

exercixe:
The cinema has n rows of m seats each. The two-dimensional array stores information about sold tickets, the number 1 means that the ticket for this seat has already been sold, the number 0 means that the seat is free. A request has been received to sell k tickets for neighboring seats in the same row. Determine whether such a request can be fulfilled.

Input data
The program receives numbers n and m as input. Then there are n lines containing m numbers (0 or 1) separated by spaces. Then the number k is given.

Output
The program should output the number of a row that has k consecutive empty seats. If there are several such rows, then print the number of the smallest suitable row. If there is no suitable row, print the number 0.

when checking, an inscription appears that there are wrong answers, but I can not understand what the error is

Answer (score 0):

I had a hard time parsing your solution, but it looks like you gave it a good try!  Here is another way to come at it that might be of use to you.  Note, it does no error checking on the input, so it is for illustration purposes only.

```
n = int(input("Rows in cinema: "))
m = int(input("Seats per row: "))

cinema_state = []
for i in range(n):
    raw_row_state = input(f"Seat states for row {i + 1}: ")
    row_state = [int(raw_seat_state) for raw_seat_state in raw_row_state]
    cinema_state.append(row_state)
    
k = int(input("Seats needed: "))

for i in range(n):
    free_row = max_free = cur_free = 0
    for j in range(m):
        seat_state = cinema_state[i][j]
        if seat_state == 0:
            cur_free += 1
            max_free = max(cur_free, max_free)
        else: # seat_state == 1
            cur_free = 0
        
    if max_free >= k:
        free_row = i + 1
        break
            
print("Free row: ", free_row)
```

Input/Output:

```
Rows in cinema:  3
Seats per row:  4
Seat states for row 1:  1010
Seat states for row 2:  1001
Seat states for row 3:  1000
Seats needed:  2
Free row:  2
```